# AngularJs Spring MVC $http.post Error 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Tags: angularjs, json, spring-mvc, http-post, http-status-code-415

Trying to send data from angularjs to Spring MVC but keeps getting 415 error

```
app.controller('RegisterFormSubmitCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', function($scope, $http) {

$scope.submit = function() {

    var registerData = {
        "email" : $scope.email,
        "firstName" : $scope.firstName,
        "lastName" : $scope.lastName,
        "DoB": $scope.DoB = new Date(),
        "password" : $scope.password
    };

    console.log(registerData);

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "http://localhost:8080/home",
        data: registerData,
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json, charset=UTF-8'
        }
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    }, function errorCallback(response) {

    });
}; }]);
```

Spring MVC controller

```
 @Consumes("text/html")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> afterRegister(@RequestBody RegisterUserRequest request){
        System.out.print("Register user: " + request.getFirstName());
        if(userManager.emailRegistered(request.getEmail())){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }
        // checking with google datastore
        else if(userManager.addUser(request.getEmail(), request.getPassword(), request.getFirstName(), request.getLastName(),
                request.getDoB(), "User")) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }
```

RegisterUserRequest class

```
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RegisterUserRequest {
    @NotNull
    private String email;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Date DoB;
    @NotNull
    private String password;
}
```

error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 415 (Unsupported Media Type)
```

I've tried removing @RequestBody notation to get rid of the error, but then the controller only receives null from `request`.
Also tried adding `produces='application/json'` in mapping, still got error 415

In dependencies I added the below to read json:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: can you post your `RegisterUserRequest` class?

Comment: I've added the `RegisterUserReques` class code

Comment: Add this dependency `<dependency>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
   <version>1.9.13</version>
  </dependency>` and check.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller `afterRegister()` method is now accepting `text/html` content i.e., `@Consumes("text/html")`, so change it to `@Consumes("application/json")`

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if your spring mvc config register the json converters
[by my another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64113269/10598034)