# Spring MVC Ajax call Post request body with 415 error

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I'm doing the demo of Spring MVC. I created ajax calling post request with data body inside but Spring seems can not recognized my request and its parameters (status 415 returned). It can't even call to my controller.

```
var jsonSTr = JSON.stringify(products);
var data = {};
data["products"] = jsonSTr;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: urlReq, --> "/mastercard/render"
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
           xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
           xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    },
   }).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    console.log(textStatus);
});
```

And this is my **java code**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/mastercard/render", method = RequestMethod.POST,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView renderToMasterCardForm(@RequestBody CheckoutRenderRequest checkoutRenderRequest) {
    List<Product> paidProducts = this.jsonToListProduct(checkoutRenderRequest.getProducts());

    ModelAndView viewModel = new ModelAndView("mastercardform");
    Response response = new Response();
    response.status = "ok";
    response.url = "mastercardform";
    response.price = String.valueOf(paidProducts.parallelStream().collect(Collectors.summarizingDouble(Product::getPrice)).getSum());
    ;
    viewModel.addObject("result", response);
    return viewModel;
 }
```

The **CheckoutRequest** class

```
private static class CheckoutRenderRequest {
    private String products;

    public String getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(String products) {
        this.products = products;
    }
}
```

I've tried with so mayny solutions but it still do not work. My code is referenced from these sites https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/spring-mvc-ajax-jquery.html, [POST JSON fails with 415 Unsupported media type, Spring 3 mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492325/post-json-fails-with-415-unsupported-media-type-spring-3-mvc), http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-4-mvc-ajax-hello-world-example/ but they do not help. I really don't know what I'm doing wrong, please help.

Answer (score 0):

The variable data don't convert by JSON.stringify，just use it.

```
var data = {products: JSON.stringify(xx)}；
$.ajax({
    data: data，
    url: xx
 })；
```

Answer (score 0):

I test your code and it works.

my ajxa (same as yours):

```
var jsonSTr = JSON.stringify({"ddd":"sss", "der":"fvgb"});
    var data = {};
    data["products"] = jsonSTr;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/mastercard/render',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    },
    }).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(textStatus);
    });
```

my controller (same as your with a little change in return value just for test):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/mastercard/render", method = RequestMethod.POST,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView renderToMasterCardForm(@RequestBody CheckoutRenderRequest checkoutRenderRequest) {
        System.out.println(checkoutRenderRequest.getProducts());

        ModelAndView viewModel = new ModelAndView("mastercardform");

        viewModel.addObject("result", "Hi");
        return viewModel;
    }
```

My entity (same as you but change private static class to public):

```
public class CheckoutRenderRequest {
    private String products;

    public String getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(String products) {
        this.products = products;
    }
}
```

MY FULL CONTROLLER:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class Test {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/mastercard/render", method = RequestMethod.POST,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView renderToMasterCardForm(@RequestBody CheckoutRenderRequest checkoutRenderRequest) {
        System.out.println(checkoutRenderRequest.getProducts());

        ModelAndView viewModel = new ModelAndView("mastercardform");

        viewModel.addObject("result", "Hi");
        return viewModel;
    }
}
```

and i called your ajax in index.jsp page

Comment: How can it work ? The controller is not called and it always get status 415. Or do you use any configs that help to map the request ?

Answer (score 0):

Add dependence

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
<artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
<version>1.2.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Try to check if your spring mvc config register the json converters

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
<mvc:message-converters register- defaults="true">
<bean class="com.alibaba.fastjson.support.spring.FastJsonHttpMessageConverter">
<property name="supportedMediaTypes">
<list>
<value>text/html;charset=UTF-8</value>
<value>application/json</value>
</list>
</property>
</bean>
</mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```